# Is there an adware-free chrome extension for mouse gestures?

Tags: linux, chrome

I'm after an extension for chrome on Linux that allows me to have a mouse gesture for duplicating a tab. Additional gestures would be nice but that is the one I really need.

I used to have Smooth Gestures installed until it [started spewing adds at me](https://superuser.com/q/724009/151431). I also saw ["Gestures for Google Chrome"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gestures-for-google-chrom/jpkfjicglakibpenojifdiepckckakgk/reviews) but the reviews say both that it doesn't work on Linux and that it too is adware.

I know of [Mouse Stroke](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mouse-stroke/aeaoofnhgocdbnbeljkmbjdmhbcokfdb/reviews) but the reviews indicate that it no longer works.

I've also seen [CrxMouse](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crxmouse/jlgkpaicikihijadgifklkbpdajbkhjo/details) but this one actually collects my IP and browsing history and shares/sells it! They even say so blatantly in their ["privacy" policy](http://addons-privacy.com/):

> We may collect results of your browsing preferences and habits, we collect information regarding your use of Our addon including URLs and Statistical Information of extensions you may be browsing while Our addon is installed. Our addon continuously and automatically transfers such information to our systems and is being collected in an aggregated manner.
>
> [...]
>
> Our addon may collect IP addresses...

My needs are simple:

1. It must work on Chrome for Linux
2. It must let me duplicate a tab with a simple mouse gesture
3. It must not collect my data or serve me with ads

Is there such an addon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an extension at all for this.

Just middle click the mouse button on the refresh icon in the browser, it will open a duplicate tab for you.

If you want to do that using keyboard you can go with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> & <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> & <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> & <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a very negligible cost (Pay-What-You-Want system, $0.25 minimum after a 1 week trial) Then I'd recommend [Smooth Gestures Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smooth-gestures-plus-adfr/kdcjmllhmhnnadianfhhnoefgcdbpdap/related?hl=en).

1. I believe so though I haven't tested it - don't have my linux thumb with me.
2. yes - hold down right button and drag a U shape
3. No ads. The [privacy policy](http://smoothgesturesplus.com/privacy) states

> The Smooth Gestures Plus software will never send your browsing
>   history or website credentials to another computer system.

Comment: Thanks but I really don't want to support an extension that silently added adds for me without letting me know so I had no idea where the ads came from.

Comment: @terdon. I'm pretty sure this is totally seperate - at least the Google page says """This extension is separate from the other "Smooth Gestures". That extension is controlled by a different group and supported by tracking and ads. "Smooth Gestures Plus" is supported by purchases and respects user privacy. See: http://smoothgesturesplus.com/privacy"""

Comment: Ah, that sounds better. However, I just [learned](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/10010/281) that I don't even need an extension for this!

Comment: @terdon yeah I saw that got posted a few hours later :)

Comment: The price is now $4 annually and $20 for lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Windrose Gestures](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/windrose-gestures/pjpodlfknhbbplpfehkigkekkjkihcdi/related). Has currently no configurability, but has all the functionality I need and no ads or tracking.